# Simplifying $(A \cup E) \cup E$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For example

$$(A^c\cap B^c)^c\cup E$$

First of all, De Morgan is definitely a must to simply this to

$$\big((A^c)^c\cup(E^c)^c\big)\cup E$$

Then double negation to remove the double complement to get

$$(A\cup E)\cup E$$

Unfortunately, how do I further simplify this statement?

Logically it seems like an absorption law to make the 3rd statement as

$$A\cup E$$

However, I'm not sure and neither is any of the law matching the 3rd statement to further simplify the statement.

Comment: You have the right idea. First use the associative law for union to rewrite $(A\cup E)\cup E$ as $A\cup(E\cup E)$, then simplify $E\cup E$.

Comment: What is the relation between $B$ and $E$? At some point you seem to use $B=E$

Comment: B? It's just asking me to simplify the set theory. Doesn't really have any relation between each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tackle it simply by definition. $x \in (A \cup E) \cup E$ means that $x$ is in one of $A \cup E$ or $E$. 'Expanding' further, we get $x$ is in one of $A, E $ or $E$. We can simplify this down to $x$ is in $A$ or $E$. i.e:  $x \in A \cup E$.

---

As noted by Brian M. Scott in the comment section, you can also use the associative law for unions to write $(A \cup E) \cup E$ as $A \cup (E \cup E)$ which is $A \cup E$.

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy:

Since $E \subseteq E \cup A$, and since for any $x \in E \cup (E \cup A)$ we have $x \in E$ or $x \in E \cup A $ and by our observasion, $x$ is always is in $E \cup A$; So we do have $E \cup (E \cup A) = E \cup A$.

And we are done.